# Using .length returns incorrect number of elements

Tags: arrays, d

When using the `.length` property of a dynamic array why does it return the incorrect number of elements **after** I use the `appender`?

If I use the `~=` syntax it returns the correct length.

Code:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.array : appender;

void main()
{
    //declaring a dynamic array
    int [] arrayofNumbers;
    //append an element using the ~= syntax
    arrayofNumbers ~= 1;
    arrayofNumbers ~= 2;
    //print the array
    writeln(arrayofNumbers);

    //Using appender
    auto appendNumber = appender(arrayofNumbers);
    appendNumber.put(10);
    writeln(appendNumber.data);

    writeln(arrayofNumbers.length);

}
```

I was reading this [article](https://dlang.org/articles/d-array-article.html#responsibility), and I think the relevant portion states:

> Another consequence of this is that the length is not an array
>   property, it's a slice property. This means the length field is not
>   necessarily the length of the array, it's the length of the slice.
>   This can be confusing to newcomers to the language.

However that is referring to slices and dynamic arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://dlang.org/library/std/array/appender.data.html) `appender.data` returns a managed array. So the correct way to get the number of elements is to call `.length` on the returned array.

Corrected Code:

```
int [] managedArray = appendNumber.data;
writeln(managedArray.length);
```

or

```
writeln(appendNumber.data.length);
```